# How do I make sure the inverse function theorem hypotheses are satisfied?

Tags: real-analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, tangent-bundle

I'm trying to prove the following result:

If $f$ is a map between two regular surfaces $S_1$ and $S_2$, $p \in S_1$, and if the differential $df_p : T_p S_1 \to T_{f(p)} S_2$ is an isomorphism (where $T_p S_1$ denotes the tangent plane to $S_1$ at $p$), then $f$ is (locally) a diffeomorphism.

The solution brings back the map $f$ to a map $g$ between Euclidean spaces, in order to apply the inverse function theorem:

It chooses $\phi_1 : U_1 \to S_1$ and $\phi_2 : U_2 \to S_2$ (where $U_i \subseteq R^2$), which are charts for $S_1$ and $S_2$, and defines $g := \phi_2^{-1} \circ f \circ \phi_1 : U_1 \to U_2$. Then, all we have left to do is to show that $g$ is a diffeomorphism: set $q = \phi_1^{-1}(p)$, then:

$dg_q = {d\phi_2^{-1}}_{f(p)} \circ df_p \circ {d\phi_1}_q$ (if I'm correct). Now, $df_p$ is an isomorphism, and, by definition, a chart $\phi$ is a smooth map such that $d\phi$ is injective. However, the solution automatically jumps to saying that $dg_q$ is invertible, and I do not know how to verify that.

Because that would require first to make sure that ${d\phi_2^{-1}}_{f(p)}$ is injective ; but even then, injectiveness of $dg_q$ would only ensure that it's a bijection on **some set**, not on the whole domain?

So how do I make sure that the inverse function theorem applies?
Thanks for your time, let me know if something is unclear.

Comment: Note that for any point $q\in U_1$ the derivative $d\phi_1q$ is a linear isomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^2$ to $T_{\phi_1(q)}S_1$.

Comment: Why is that so? I thought the only requirement for $\phi$ to be a chart was for $d\phi$ to be injective, how do we ensure surjectivity?

Comment: Oh wait, I think I got it. Any vector of $T_{\phi_q} S_1$ can be written as $a\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial u} + b\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial v}$. And this can be written as: $\dfrac{d}{dt}\phi(at, bt) = d\phi_q (a,b)$, right?